# Pandas read_csv() 1.2GB file out of memory on VM with 140GB RAM

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to read a CSV file of 1.2G, which contains 25K records, each consists of a id and a large string.

However, around 10K rows, I get this error:

> pandas.io.common.CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: out of memory

Which seems weird, since the VM has 140GB RAM and at 10K rows the memory usage is only at ~1%.

This is the command I use:

```
pd.read_csv('file.csv', header=None, names=['id', 'text', 'code'])
```

I also ran the following dummy program, which could successfully fill up my memory to close to 100%.

```
list = []
list.append("hello")
while True:
    list.append("hello" + list[len(list) - 1])
```

Comment: did you try to use `chunksize` parameter and to read your file in chunks?

Comment: @MaxU then it would return an iterator and I would have to handle that in my code which I want to avoid if possible

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This sounds like a job for `chunksize`. It splits the input process into multiple chunks, reducing the required reading memory.

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
for chunk in pd.read_csv('Check1_900.csv', header=None, names=['id', 'text', 'code'], chunksize=1000):
    df = pd.concat([df, chunk], ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: I would do it in a loop concatenating each chunk to the resulting DF: `df = pd.DataFrame(); for x in pd.read_csv(...): df = pd.concat([df, x], ignore_index=True)` - so we won't need RAM for __all__ chunks plus for the resulting DF

Comment: Wow, nice :) Thanks, it works perfectly. Do you now, why the original approach fails?

Comment: @DavidFrank You originally did not split file into chunks, resulting in too much memory being needed to read the file. Reading the smaller chunks was doable for your memory constraints.

Comment: @kilojoules But I have more than 100 times as much memory as required by the file, where did the overhead come from?

Comment: @DavidFrank, what is your pandas version?

Comment: @DavidFrank My broad understanding is that python's way of reading the file is memory-intensive. Even representing integer values is surprisingly memory intensive in python.

Comment: This is like running away from problem, there something wrong when reading 1.2GB file into RAM and it takes 140GB

Comment: @JemshitIskenderov It does not say it takes 140GB, only that is the theoretical available memory space.

Comment: Pandas DF takes 30% more than what it is necessary to store all values.  I concur with @Jemshit.  The reading of CSV file and loading it to dataframe should not cause any memory related issue.

Answer (score 4):

This is weird.

Actually I ran into the same situation.

```
df_train = pd.read_csv('./train_set.csv')
```

But after I tried a lot of stuff to solve this error. And it works.
Like this:

```
dtypes = {'id': pd.np.int8,
          'article':pd.np.str,
          'word_seg':pd.np.str,
          'class':pd.np.int8}
df_train = pd.read_csv('./train_set.csv', dtype=dtypes)
df_test = pd.read_csv('./test_set.csv', dtype=dtypes)
```

Or this:

```
ChunkSize = 10000
i = 1
for chunk in pd.read_csv('./train_set.csv', chunksize=ChunkSize): #分块合并
    df_train = chunk if i == 1 else pd.concat([df_train, chunk])
    print('-->Read Chunk...', i)
    i += 1
```

BUT!!!!!Suddenlly the original version works fine as well!

**Like I did some useless work and I still have no idea where really went wrong**.

I don't know what to say.

Comment: I also faced similar frustrations of inconsistency. However since it's a memory error, it makes sense that it can be inconsistent in when the error occurs.  E.g. An outside process that you're not aware of which is running can eat up memory, or maybe the garbage collector decided to collect during the successful times.  I still believe it's best to go with the safer approach and use one of the methods you found that reduce memory consumption to avoid future errors.  So I don't think your work was wasted.

Answer (score 3):

This error can occur with an invalid csv file, rather than the stated memory error.

I got this error with a file that was much smaller than my available RAM and it turned out that there was an opening double quote on one line without a closing double quote.

In this case, you can check the data, or you can change the quoting behavior of the parser, for example by passing `quoting=3` to `pd.read_csv`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the command `df.info(memory_usage="deep")`, to find out the memory usage of data being loaded in the data frame.

Few things to reduce Memory:

1. Only load columns you need in the processing via `usecols` table.
2. Set `dtypes` for these columns
3. If your dtype is Object / String for some columns, you can try using the `dtype="category"`. In my experience it reduced the memory usage drastically.

Answer (score 0):

I used the below code to load csv in chunks while removing the intermediate file to manage memory, and view % of loading in real time:
Note: 96817414 is the number of rows in my csv

```
import pandas as pd
import gc
cols=['col_name_1', 'col_name_2', 'col_name_3']
df = pd.DataFrame()
i = 0
for chunk in pd.read_csv('file.csv', chunksize=100000, usecols=cols):
    df = pd.concat([df, chunk], ignore_index=True)
    del chunk; gc.collect()
    i+=1
    if i%5==0:
        print("% of read completed", 100*(i*100000/96817414))
```

Comment: concatenating them right after you read them is one of the worst ways to handle memory. You keep copying everything around the memory.